# How do I solve $xy' + y \sin(x) =\ln(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation: $xy' + y \sin(x) = \ln(x)$

I quickly realized that it was not linearly separable, so then I tried to get it into $M(x, y)dx + N(x, y)dy = 0$ form:

$$
x\frac{dy}{dx} + y \sin(x) = \ln(x) \\
x\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(x) - y \sin(x) \\
x dy = (\ln(x) - y\sin(x)) dx \\
x dy - (\ln(x) - y\sin(x)) dx = 0 \\
x dy + (y\sin(x) - \ln(x)) dx = 0
$$

However $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x} \not = \dfrac{\partial (y\sin(x) - \ln(x))}{\partial y} = \sin(x)$.

What else can I do to solve this equation. This is not homework. It's a book problem from a linear algebra textbook. I'm reviewing it for background before taking differential geometry.

Comment: Often times it can help to solve the homogeneous version of the differential equation and then adjust for the inhomogeneous part.  In this case, we find that $xy'+ y \sin x =0$ yields $y=c\exp (\int^x \sin(t)/t dt)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get
$$y'+y\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

which is a first order linear ordinary differential equation. This is of the form
$$ y' + y\cdot P(x)=Q(x)$$
whose solution is given by
$$y\cdot e^{\int P(x)dx}=\int \left[Q(x)\cdot e^{\int P(x)dx} dx\right] + C.$$

So, the solution of the given DE is
$$y\cdot e^{\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx}=\int \left[\frac{\ln x}{x}\cdot e^{\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx} dx\right] + C.$$